# Is there a wonder, project or political choice that forbids you to declare war?

Tags: civilization-5

In previous versions of Civilization, I think that there were some buildings or wonders that will prevent you from declaring war to other civilizations (because of your people's disagreement). I think maybe NATO or the UN ? Or choosing Pure Democracy ?

Is there something like that in the 5th version of the game ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only a peace treaty removes your ability to declare war, and then only for its duration (10 turns).

People aren't unhappy due to wars.  Unhappiness is just generated by population count and number of cities (with extra from occupied cities without courthouses, puppets, razing).